# Identify the correct points enclosed by unstructured set of points

Tags: python, geometry

I have an unstructured set of points (X,Y) as in the picture shown with blue

[image]

I am interested in identifying the orange points (structured) which are in the white/empty spaces within the blue points. Can someone please suggest a good/structured way of approaching this problem.

Comment: The problem is so ill-defined that I can't tell what it's talking about. Are you given the set of original points, and how? (show some code) What does "in the white space" mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your unstructured points into an image, you can use [morphological transformations](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html).

For example, you can apply a gradually larger *closing transformation* until you get an inner region that's not connected to the outer region.